# need some help about maven

Tags: maven

we have several projects in our company with many dependencies among them. we have gathered our projects (EJB,Web, Enterprise Application and ...), on a SVN server, now we have difficulties with our projects, because after checking out a project from SVN, we have to waste a long time to gather the required libraries and projects for the checked-out project to build.

i want to some help about that, how the maven technology could help us to easily gather the dependencies and build our projects automatically. we use myeclipse IDE.

moreover i need some help and resources, to learn how to achieve this goal.

any guide and help will be appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the amount of projects you have, and how complex their build is, switching to Maven can be a hell of a task. It might still be worthwhile, mainly because Maven forces you to do things "the Maven way"<sup>1</sup>, and that such a "Maven way" is becoming more standard with time: you might end up with a simplified/more standardized build procedure.

If your projects are currently built using [ant](http://ant.apache.org/), chances are that [ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) can quite more easily solve your problem of offloading JARs from your VCS system, with a minimal impact to your current build configuration.

Otherwise, if you really think Maven is the right tool for you, I strongly suggest you to have a look at the official [tutorial](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html), the [POM reference](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html) and start playing with simple, self generated projects to start having an idea about how to deal with Maven. Using the `archetype:generate` mechanism you have access to dozens (hundreds?) of sample projects ([archetypes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html), in Maven jargon) that illustrate you how to deal with different kinds of projects, from simple JAR to more complex ones, maybe leveraging exotic frameworks or products. Have a look at the generated POM for such projects and try to understand how it works.

Integration with Eclipse is achieved via [two different plugins](http://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html). I'm not using Eclipse anymore since quite a while, but I think [m2eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) is still probably the best one to start with.

1- WARN: his is one of the things people coming to Maven heavily dislike more often than not